# Ruby on Rails - Google Maps API - Displaying multiple markers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I stored the json in a variable in the application controller using HTTParty. The map displays all of the markers. The problem occurs when a marker is clicked in order to view the info window. No matter which marker is clicked, the last marker in the array's info window appears. Do you have a solution using the code that I have? I am also not sure if this is best practice mixing ruby with javascript like I did. Any input on this too would also be greatly appreciated.

The javascript which is in application.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 35.50, lng: -98.5},
      zoom: 4
    };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    <% @place['ymca'].each do |p| %>


      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: 'hello'
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: { lat: <%= p['lat'] %>, lng: <%= p['lon'] %>},
          map: map,
          title: 'Random',

      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    <% end %>
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

application_controller.rb:

```
def parse
  uri = HTTParty.get"http://www.livestrong.org/we-can-help/ymca.json"
  @place = JSON.parse(uri.body)
end
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I already used this as a reference and was not able to figure out a solution to this problem. [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: how could you know that always the last `infowindow` content is showing?? For all the markers you've used the same `content` **hello**. So, all the markers have the same content right?

Comment: I looked at the json array and the location of the last item in the array matches the point on the map. I just used hello as a temporary place holder until I get everything working. Any marker that is clicked on opens that same info window that is in the same location.